# IdentityServer4 and Getting Multiple Applications to Share Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I've been having a lot of trouble across different examples implementing a single sign on or similar feature with identity server. Given an IDServ Startup.cs config of

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
```

And two clients:

```
services.AddMvc();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
```

+

```
services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddJsonFormatters();

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Audience = "api1";
                });
```

I always run into some kind of problem getting the second client to redirect to the Auth server when the request doesn't already come with a valid token. I've given the above for examples, but it seems to persist across whether client2 has `AddCookie` as the first one does, or whether one or both of them use `AddJwtBearer`, etc. After a few days of mashing different combinations of config I feel the need to ask what the important parts of config are that cause a client to redirect to the IdentityServer's Authentication/Login Page, and how to get multiple clients playing nice with sharing Auth between each other.

I've found the IdentityServer canonical examples (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/aspnetcore2/samples/Quickstarts/ ) , but they don't give good coverage of this : as in the above example (i took the snippets from QS #3, only the first client redirects, and the second will just 401 if it doesn't already have a valid bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

First thing as per your code there is only 1 client you have configured using `AddOpenIdConnect` in IdentityServer4.

Your mentioned second client is API Resource/Audience for the IDS. Which get authenticated with token of mentioned client with `AddOpenIdConnect`.

Better you can review examples like below.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html